# Custom entity field in Easyadmin

Tags: easyadmin, symfony6

I have a CMS.

Table structure is:

```
page
---
id
parent_id - id of parent page
slug
title
```

I needed to render parents in edit form as choices like this:

```
(root)
foo
foo > bar
blah
blah > blah2
blah > blah2 > blah3
```

In Easyadmin edit form configuration, I did like this:

```
        return [
            ChoiceField::new('parent', 'Parent page')
                ->setChoices($pages),
            ...
        ];
```

When I define field 'parent' (as example above), all renders good. But on saving I get error: "Expected argument of type "?App\Entity\Page", "int" given at property path "parent"."

When I define field 'parentId', I get error on form rendering: "Can't get a way to read the property "parentId" in class "App\Entity\Page"."

I'm using EasyAdmin 4.6.5, Doctrine 2.5, Symfony 6.1.